# Redirect after POST request with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post, redirect

I'm working with Django. I have an HTML page, where I do some Javascript stuff, and then I do a jQuery post, in this way:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: '/xenopatients/measurement/qual', 
  type: 'POST', 
  data: {'obj':data}, 
  dataType: 'json', 
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //questo ok 
});
```

After this post request, my Django view correctly handles the call for this URL. 
What I want it to do is process the data, send the user to another page, and send this data to the new page.
The problem is that I cannot perform the redirect like usual in Python, it's like the code ignores the redirect.

My Python code is:

```
@csrf_protect 
@login_required#(login_url='/xenopatients/login/') 
def qualMeasure(request): 
    name = request.user.username 
    print "enter" 
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        print request.POST 

        if "obj" in request.POST: 
            print 'obj received' 
            return render_to_response('mice/mice_status.html', RequestContext(request)) 

    return render_to_response('measure/qual.html', {'name': name, 'form': QualMeasureForm()}, RequestContext(request))
```

The only way I've found to change the page is through Javascript after the code above:

```
top.location.href = "/xenopatients/measurement";
```

But I don't know how to pass the data I need when using this method.

The HTML code:

```
<form action="" method=""> 
  <table id="dataTable" width="100%" border="1"></table><br> 
  <script language="javascript"> 
    document.measureForm.id_barcode.focus(); 
    document.measureForm.Add.disabled = false; 
    $('#dataTable').tablePagination({}); 
  </script> 
  <input type="button" name="save" value="Save Measure Serie" onclick="table2JSON('dataTable')"/> 
</form>
```

P.S. I've also tried `$.post`, but with the same results.

How can I do a redirect after a post request made with jQuery in Django?

Comment: If you want to redirect, why are you doing it with Ajax? Why not submit the form in the normal way? The main reason for using Ajax is to avoid redirections.

Comment: I use ajax to change dynamically the data of page and for send complex data to the server... and I not the unique! ;)

Comment: The python code isn't very readable, because something is wrong with identation...

Comment: @acidjunk thanks, I never saw that error. Now I've fixed it. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I've found the magical solution! :)

The situation:
there is a view's method called by jQUery.ajax()

To redirect after Ajax, I've used the tips found [here](http://hunterford.me/how-to-handle-http-redirects-with-jquery-and-django/) (use document instead of 'body' in the jQuery selecotor)

But, I've had also further operations to do.

in the called view, call another method, like this:

```
[...]
if request.method == 'POST':
    if "obj" in request.POST: #ricevuti dati da ajax
        request.session['qual'] = request.POST['obj']
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("xenopatients.views.qualReport"))
```

I save the data that I need in the session. I use this data in the called view.

Call another method it's the key for redirect the page of the browser.
In fact, at the end of the called method, you can normally write&execute:

```
return render_to_response('measure/qualReport.html', {'name':name, 'list_report': report, 'message':'Measures correctly saved'}, RequestContext(request))
```

Hope this can be useful for someone! ;)

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel is correct in that you want to avoid redirects with ajax calls, but you might take a look at this Stack Overflow question which addresses how to do so: [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: this is like my solution i think.. in your link i don't find useful information for me..  there aren't information about send data in post via js or redirect via python after the post! :(

Answer (score 1):

On button click call this function() below and pass the parameter, in my case I passed new

```
function checkforNew(){
                //jQuery.post('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/InspectionController?&oper=new');

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MyController?&oper=new',
                    //data: {'obj':data},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response){
                        window.location.href = response.redirect;
                    }
                });
            }
```

Inside your servlet you need to mention following code, for the page to redirect.

```
String destination = "/mypage.jsp;

                response.setContentType("application/json");
                JSONObject responsedata = new JSONObject();
                responsedata.put("redirect", destination);

                out.print(responsedata);
                out.flush();
```

Comment: found it does not work, but it works with a callback function after ajax